# Uploading Styled HTML to Google Docs

Tags: google-drive, html, css

I find that when I upload Styled HTML to Google Docs, eg. with CSS

```
.underline { text-decoration: underline; }
.del { text-decoration: line-through; }
mark { background: yellow }
```

None of these will take effect. However if I use CSS produced when downloading a Google Docs as HTML like

```
.c9 {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

It works. Can I say that Google does not take into considerations any CSS?

Comment: What about inline CSS?

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Google Docs strips (most) CSS and the feature to edit HTML or edit CSS will not be returning.

https://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=176442

I presume this is done to maintain consistency across multiple devices, especially mobile, which now supports document editing.

---

Here's another discussion with a possible (temporary) workaround:

- [What happened to 'Edit CSS' in Google docs?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/327/what-happened-to-edit-css-in-google-docs)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add  : !important like

> underline {text-decoration: underline
>   !important;}