# Have Google removed the option to roll back to the old Google docs version?

Tags: google-drive

I tried following the advice given in another thread for [rolling back the google docs version to the old one](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/327/what-happened-to-edit-css-in-google-docs), but I couldn't find the option in the Editing section of the google docs settings.

Can anyone confirm that this is the case, that google have removed the ability to roll back to the old google docs version.  The old version allows for editing the html and css of documents and this is the main reason I want to use it over the new version.

Is there a way of linking to a plain text version of a document, without any html or css styling?

Comment: you're not the only one who wants that feature..! :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Google has removed the feature to roll back to the previous version. Whenever Google Changes it user-interface (for any of its services), it's in a testing phase and the users are allowed to switch back to the old one and also give comments on the new one. This is just to see if there are a sufficient number of users who are finding the new-interface comfortable and also so that if there happens to be any bug in the new interface, the users can easily roll back and continue with their work.

After the testing phase is over, and google is sure that there are no bugs in the new interface and that the majority of the users are happy with it, the option of the old interface vanishes.

This has happened several times in GMail.